# Show More/Show Less CSS JS Animation not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some texts in my site that I want to show only when the user clicks at the title and then the text appears with an animation, and when the user clicks again at the title the text disappears. I made this code bellow that is working awesome for "show more" but for some reason its not working for "show less"!

```js
function showMore(resp) {
  if (document.getElementById(resp).style.maxHeight == "400") {
    document.getElementById(resp).style.animation = "showmore 2s ease-in-out reverse";
    document.getElementById(resp).style.maxHeight = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(resp).style.animation = "showmore 2s ease-in-out";
    document.getElementById(resp).style.maxHeight = "400";
  }
}
```

```css
@keyframes showmore {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 400px;
  }
}

.awr {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 17;
  color: dimgrey;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="question" onclick="showMore('awr1')">
  <h3>How it Works?</h3>
</div>
<div class="awr" id="awr1">
  <p>this is the text that must be hidden.</p>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: First write CSS for two classes `.hide` _(height: 0px;)_ and `.show` _(height: 400px;)_. Then toggle the classes when user clicks on the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with css `transition` instead of `animation`.  Transition basically watches the given properties for changes and animates it from one state to the next.  You can also use the all keyword here if you just want everything to animate when it's changed.

```
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 400px;
}
.awr {
  /* your other styles here */
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, easing is default behavior, too.  Then toggle the class with JavaScript however you usually would.  For example, this is my preferred method:

```
const showMore = resp => document.querySelector(`#${resp}`).classList.toggle('show')
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented in jQuery but you can easily transform into Javascript.

You can simply add a class & toggle it.

```js
function showMore(resp) {
  $("#" + resp).toggleClass("show");
}
```

```css
.awr {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 17;
  color: dimgrey;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question" onclick="showMore('awr1')">
  <h3>How it Works?</h3>
</div>
<div class="awr" id="awr1">
  <p>this is the text that must be hidden.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think animation only works with a predefined @keyframes name.  Transition might be what you need.

Comment: @JonDeWitt Yes. I mistaken them & wonder why it does not work as I expected. Thanks